# How can I find the longest increasing section of numbers at list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

For example list `[1,3,4,3,6,7,3]` gives result `[1,3,4]` or `[3,6,7]`. I can find only subsequence but not a section.

### Edit

By Naive implementation I find subsequence

```
increasing :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
increasing = maximumBy (comparing length) . map nub 
                                          . filter isSorted
                                          . subsequences
```

Comment: hi, welcome to stackoverflow and haskell! Can you tell us - what have you tried, where are you stuck - what functions of `Data.List` can you think of that would be helpful?

Comment: [By Naive implementation I find subsequence but not a sequence] increasing :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] 
increasing = maximumBy (comparing length) . map nub . filter isSorted . subsequences

Comment: What do you mean by "section"?

Comment: I don't know the word, may be line segment? For example [5,4,2,1] result
--[5], [4], [2] or [1]. And for [3,2,6,4,5,1] result [2, 6] or [4, 5].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary-predicate cut of a sequence; the cut occurs at the first pair `(x1, x2)` for which `x1 <> x2` doesn’t hold:

```
biCut :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
biCut (<>) (x1 : xs@(x2 : _)) | x1 <> x2  = let (tk, dp) = biCut (<>) xs
                                            in  (x1 : tk, dp)
                              | otherwise = ([x1], xs)
biCut _    xs                             = (xs, [])
```

(analogous to `splitAt`) or in terms of

```
biFst :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
biFst (<>) (x1 : xs@(x2 : _)) | x1 <> x2  = x1 : biFst (<>) xs
                              | otherwise = [x1]
biFst _    xs                             = xs

biSnd :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
biSnd (<>) (x1 : xs@(x2 : _)) | x1 <> x2  = biSnd (<>) xs
                              | otherwise = xs
biSnd _    _                              = []
```

(`take` and `drop`) such that `forall (<>) xs.`

```
biFst (<>) xs ++ biSnd (<>) xs  =  xs
                 biCut (<>) xs  =  (biFst (<>) xs, biSnd (<>) xs)    [CUT]
```

then

```
sections :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
sections _    [] = []
sections (<>) xs = let (tk, dp) = biCut (<>) xs
                   in  tk : sections (<>) dp
```

such that

```
        concat . sections (<>)  =  id
```

“Sections” are non-empty subsequences for which the binary predicate `<>` holds between successors. Reformulating the standard `maximumBy` as a *total function*:

```
maximumBy :: Foldable t => (a -> a -> Ordering) -> t a -> Maybe a
maximumBy cmp xs | null xs   = Nothing
                 | otherwise = Just (foldl1 max' xs)
   where
      max' x y = case x `cmp` y of
                    LT -> y            -- Leftmost-biased
                    _  -> x
```

Then

```
longestAsc :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe [a]
longestAsc = maximumBy (compare `on` length) . sections (<)
```

is the function.

```
      longestAsc [2,3,2,1,2,3]  =  Just [1,2,3]
              longestAsc [2,1]  =  Just [2]
                 longestAsc []  =  Nothing
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you use case expressions over pattern matching in the function definition? Also do you know that you can pattern match on `(x:y:xy)`?

Comment: ah - it is just a matter of style - +1 for including the alternative style

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are on a good way - and you already seem to know a lot - so I won't spoil the result for you.

At first I think you should change the type signature of your function

```
increasingSequences :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
```

There is already one function that promises to be a solution to that problem from `Data.List` namely - `groupBy`, in the form of `groupBy (<=)`.

But `groupBy` does not work as expected, it compares with the first element of each group - which is ok for `groupBy (==)` - but not for your case.

```
> ghci
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/epsilonhalbe/.ghc/ghci.conf
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List> groupBy (<=) [10,9..6]
[[10],[9],[8],[7],[6]]
Prelude Data.List> groupBy (<=) (1:[10,9..6])
[[1,10,9,8,7,6]]
```

so you need to implement that one yourself - the easiest version IMHO would be to use pattern matching and recursion - **I would strongly suggest writing it and posting it here as an answer (I will check in the next few days and vote that one up if you do!)**

If you *really* want a spoiler there is actually a [wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_function_suggestions#Generalize_groupBy_and_friends) that gives a solution to your problem.

> `groupBy                 :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
> groupBy rel []          =  []
> groupBy rel (x:xs)      =  (x:ys) : groupBy rel zs
>     where (ys,zs) = groupByAux x xs
>           groupByAux x0 (x:xs) | rel x0 x = (x:ys, zs)
>             where (ys,zs) = groupByAux x xs
>           groupByAux y xs = ([], xs)`

Comment: Ok, thanks you. I understood this one. Also a question: if I need a function increasingSequences :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] with only one sequence in result? What should I use?

Comment: what do you need - any one? the first one ? the longest one? - you can use ``head . sortBy (compare `on` length)``, in combination with this one - you just need to make sure that the original list is not empty - otherwise `head` will fail.